# So many errors and not sure how to fix it

Tags: c

I'm currently still practicing my c programming skills but there are so many errors here that I'm confuse on what is wrong and how to fix it. It's for a database program that I was practicing on.

It keeps showing:

> new2.c:86: error: request for member ‘previousreading’ in something not a structure or union

and

> new2.c:94: error: ‘Break’ undeclared (first use in this function)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int custid;
    char custname;
    float currentreading;
    float previousreading;
    double charge;
    int choice;
    unsigned cust;
    int revenue, meterdifference, BILL;

    printf("----------------------------------\n");
    printf("Electricity Management System\n");
    printf("----------------------------------\n"); 
    printf("\n1. Record Usage");
    printf("\n2. Add Customer");
    printf("\n3. Edit Customer");
    printf("\n4. Delete Customer");
    printf("\n5. Show Customer");
    printf("\n6. Show Total monthly income");
    printf("\n7. Exit");


    scanf("%d",&choice);

    if(choice >=1 || choice <=7) 
    { 
    switch(choice) 
        { 
            case 1: //Record Usage 
            printf("Enter Customer ID\n");

            FILE *cfPtr; 
            if ((cfPtr = fopen("customer.txt", "r"))== NULL)
                puts("This file could not be opened");
            else
                {
                    puts("Enter the customer ID, name."); 
                    scanf("%d%29s", &cust.custid, cust.custname); 
                    puts("Enter the current reading in kWh"); 
                    scanf("%d", cust.currentreading); 

                    if(cust.currentreading < cust.previousreading)
                    puts("Input invalid");
                    else 
                    {
                        if (cust.currentreading>=200) 
                            {
                            cust.charge = (cust.currentreading - cust.previousreading)*21.80; 
                            printf("\nThe charge is RM%f\n", &cust.charge); 
                            }
                        else 
                        {
                            if (cust.currentreading>=300)
                                {
                                cust.charge= ((cust.currentreading - cust.previousreading)*33.40)+21.80; 
                                printf("\nThe charge is RM%f", &cust.charge); 
                                }
                            else 
                            {
                                if (cust.currentreading>=600)
                                    {
                                        cust.charge= ((cust.currentreading - cust.previousreading)*51.60)+21.80; 
                                        printf("\nThe charge is RM%f", &cust.charge); 
                                    }
                                else 
                                    {
                                    if (currentreading>=900)
                                        {
                                        cust.charge = ((cust.currentreading - cust.previousreading)*54.60)+21.80; 
                                        printf("\nThe charge is RM%f", &cust.charge);
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                        cust.charge = ((cust.currentreading - cust.previousreading)*57.10)+21.80; 
                                        printf("\nThe charge is RM%f", &cust.charge);
                                        }
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            Break; 

            case2: //Add Customer 
            puts("This option allows user to add new customer"); 
            printf("Enter Customer ID and name."); 
            scanf("%d%c", &cust.custid, cust.custname);
            puts("To return to menu");
            Break; 

            case 3: //Edit Customer 
            puts( "This option allows user to edit customer info"); 
            Break; 

            case 4: //delete customer 
            puts( "This option allows user to delete customer"); 
            Break; 

            case 5: //Show Customer 
            printf("To show customer information\n"); 
            FILE*tPtr;
            char custid[100],custname[100];
            int previousreading,currentreading;
            double charge;

            printf("\n Show Customer\n");
            if((tPtr= fopen("customer.txt","r"))==NULL){
            puts("File not found");
                }

            else{
                printf("%-15s%-25s%-20s%-15s%-15s\n","ID","Name","Previous Reading","Current Reading","Charges");
                    while(!feof(tPtr)){
                        fscanf(tPtr,"%[^;];%[^;];%d;%d;%lf",cust.custid,cust.custname,&cust.previousreading,&cust.currentreading,&cust.charge);
                        printf("%s\t\t%-25s%-20d%-15d%-15.2lf",cust.custid,cust.custname,cust.previousreading,cust.currentreading,cust.charge);
                    }
                    fclose(tPtr);
                }
                printf("\n\n");
                Break; 

            case 6: //Show total income(monthly) 
            puts("To show monthyly income"); 
            printf("total usagekWh, meterdifference"); 
            printf("%-15s%-35.2d\n", "Total UsagekWh","meterdifference"); 
            scanf("%-16dtotal usage(kWh)%-24d: %.2f",&meterdifference); 
            printf("%-13dtotal revenue%-24d: %.2f",BILL);
            revenue=BILL; 
            printf("revenue is %.2f", BILL);
            Break; 

            case 7: //Exit 
            Break; 
        }
    }
    else
    printf("\nError. Number not in choices.");

return 0;
}

typedef struct{
        int custid[50];
        char custname[100];
        int previousreading;
        int currentreading;
        float charges;
}cust;
```

Comment: It's `break` not `Break`. C is case-sensitive.

Comment: When you have so many errors, start by fixing the first error reported by the compiler. Often this will fix other errors that follow. Recompile and repeat.

Comment: Please go back to your studies as you have clearly not understood structures at all.

Answer (score 3):

1. Put the `typedef` **before** `main`. `typedef`s must occure *before* you use them just as vaiables.
2. Replace `unsigned cust;` by `cust cust;`. `unsigned cust;` is the same as `unsigned int cust;` and declares an unsigned integer, you want to declare a `cust`.
3. Replace `float charges;` by `float charge;` in the `typedef`
4. Replace `Break;` by `break;`. Case matters in C. `Break` is not `Break`, just as `Int` is not `int`.

Then it compiles.

Now if it it runs correctly or not is another story.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a single structure in your code, not in the form of a variable declaration nor as a type definition<sup>1</sup>, and you are treating `cust` which is simply an unsigned `int` as if it was a structure, perhaps you mean

```
struct {
    float previousreading;
    float currentreading;
    /* And so on */
} cust;
```

Also, there is no `Break` keyword in c, it's `break`, all lower case.

But,

1. Don't do it, create a new `struct` so that you can use declare variables of type `struct Costumer` for example. Like at the end of your code, except that the compiler needs to know about it before using it, and the `cust` variable should have it's type.
2. A `char` is not a string type, if you want a string you need an array of `char`, so `char custname;` is not going to work for the *name* string.
3. Use meaningful names for your variables, and the members if your structure and the type name too. Like `costumer` instead of `cust`.

**Additional NOTE**

See [Why `while (!foef(file))` is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong). Your code will always attempt a read with `fscanf()` that will fail but it proceeds to print the data, it's very likely that your last row is printed twice once you make the code compile.

Instead, check the return value of `fscanf()`, if you don't know what it returns and don't fully understand it you can always read [fscanf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) documentation.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>At least not before you attempt to use it.</sub>